# Java source folder created automatically in gradle+groovy project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, groovy

I tried to create gradle groovy project in Intelij IDEA 2017.3
By in created projcet I found java source and test folder.Look like they were automatically generated.

Do you know how that creation can be disabled?

[image: project structure]

P.s I know that I can delete them manually but If add one more project to the existing -> folders will be added automatically again to all projects.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the option *Create directories for empty content roots* under *Settings* -> *Build, Execution, Deployment* -> *Build Tools* -> *Gradle*?

Comment: @lu.koerfer Yes, I tried. 
Checkbox _create directories for empty content roots_ unchecked in settings

Comment: but nothing was changed(

Comment: Did IntelliJ recreate the folders after unchecking the option? Or did it just not delete them? I think you still need to delete them a last time.

Comment: @lu.koerfer
Yeah. This option was unchecked by default. But folders still created. Even after delete. But in idea 2017.1 I didn't meet this problem. In 2017.2 - it was present

Comment: @lu.koerfer
Thank you so much for your advises. I found how to resolve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way works for me:

1. Create empty gradle project
2. Create src folder
3. Run build.gradle file (file should be without *apply plugin: groovy'* string)
4. In build.gradle file add apply plugin: 'groovy'
5. Build project again
6. Manually create folders main/groovy and test/groovy

Answer (score 0):

I found how to resolve this issue:

1. Create empty gradle project
2. In build.gradle file add *apply plugin: 'groovy'*
3. Manually create folders src/main/groovy and src/test/groovy