# Tell gradle project should have no src folder

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project and it has a whole bunch of gradle submodules in it, but it has no src of it's own.

Every time I add a new module it tries to regenerate the src folder and it's sub-directories.

This is what my settings.gradle looks like

```
rootProject.name = 'leetcodejava'
include 'problem1'
include 'problem2'
include 'problem206'
```

Is there a way I can tell gradle to not attempt to re-create the src directory for this project?

Comment: I've never known Gradle to automatically create source folders. Are you using an IDE? Some non-standard plugins?

Comment: Yeah I'm using intelliJ IDEA, and creating the new gradle module via the ui.  Maybe that's the issue

Comment: You meant it's from your `settings.gradle` file ?

Comment: Yes sorry `settings.gradle`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java source folder created automatically in gradle+groovy project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073093/java-source-folder-created-automatically-in-gradlegroovy-project)

Comment: Could you share your `build.gradle` relevant part ?